# Errors when declaring multimap in function definition of C++ Class or just as a variable to use

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, syntax-error

I'm trying to use a function within a class, which has a multimap as a parameter but I always get an error - "Overloaded function not found in 'TdOpenGLGraphs'" and I don't understand why. I made sure it was all public so there are no permission issues, I've declared it in the class in the .h file and the .cpp file exactly the same (I even got intellisense to do it for me so there were no typos) and no luck. I've included the correct  header too  but i still get the error

I also get:

"missing type specifier = int assumed. Note C++ does not support default-int."
and "syntax error: missing ',' before '<'"

even if I just declare a multimap as part of the class.

In the Header file:

```
class TdOpenGLGraphs
{
public:
//TdOpenGLGraphs();
//~TdOpenGLGraphs();

//This is the problem function
    void CreateGraph(int iCurrGraphID, const multimap<int, double>& mDataToDisp);
public:
//This also produces an error   
//multimap<int, double>mCurrData;

        
};
```

The .cpp File

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "TdOpenGLGraphs.h"

using namespace std;

void TdOpenGLGraphs::CreateGraph(int iCurrGraphID, const multimap<int, double>& mDataToDisp)
{

}
```

Comment: Your header file should `#include <map>` and the parameter type should use the namespace qualifier: `const std::multimap<int, double>&`

Comment: I have included the <map> header file though. Anyway tried the using namespace std and it still doesn't work...

Comment: So, just to clarify, in your _header file_ in the class declaration, you wrote `std::multimap` everywhere you're using that type?  And it still doesn't compile?  If so, you need to update your question with a more complete example.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Have you included the map header in the .h file? Also, avoid the
`using namespace std;` part, rather write everywhere std::map etc.

Comment: This is not an answer, and in fact covers what I already wrote in the comments.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).